# how to create rtsp stream server using netty

Tags: java, c++

Pls help me to create rtsp server. if there are any working example.. I try to netty example.

[Link for github](https://github.com/darkmi/rtspserver)

but display the following error,

```
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Failed to load bean class: com.darkmi.server.config.ServerConfig; nested exception is java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [application.properties] cannot be opened because it does not exist
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.processConfigBeanDefinitions(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:267)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.postProcessBeanDefinitionRegistry(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:203)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:622)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:451)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext.<init>(AnnotationConfigApplicationContext.java:73)
    at com.darkmi.server.Main.main(Main.java:14)
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [application.properties] cannot be opened because it does not exist
    at org.springframework.core.io.ClassPathResource.getInputStream(ClassPathResource.java:157)
    at org.springframework.core.io.support.ResourcePropertySource.loadPropertiesForResource(ResourcePropertySource.java:101)
    at org.springframework.core.io.support.ResourcePropertySource.<init>(ResourcePropertySource.java:43)
    at org.springframework.core.io.support.ResourcePropertySource.<init>(ResourcePropertySource.java:52)
    at org.springframework.core.io.support.ResourcePropertySource.<init>(ResourcePropertySource.java:82)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.doProcessConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassParser.java:193)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.processConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassParser.java:149)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.parse(ConfigurationClassParser.java:135)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.processConfigBeanDefinitions(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:260)
```

Comment: what is rtsp? And code will be VERY helpfull. EDIT and what this have to C++ ?

Comment: @Jacek Cz RTSP is Real-Time Streaming Protocol. Used to stream different kinds of media over UDP.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a resources folder in your eclipse project. and then add that folder to your project sources. application.properties file (which contains IP/Port of RTSP server) should be located there.

[image: It should look something like this]